# Dúvida na utilização do for

Tags: c, for

Preciso fazer um código para resolver a seguinte questão: Tenho uma cesta com capacidade C, tenho 3 tipos de frutas, receberei a quantidade um por linha, para por todas elas na cesta, a coleta dessas frutas se leva 1 minuto.
Por exemplo:
Cesta = 12
A = 4
B = 3
C = 3
Saída: 1
Cesta = 10
A = 5
B = 5
C = 5
Saída = 2(porque precisou de duas viagens, ou seja, dois minutos.)
Como fazer usando `for`? procuro a forma mais simples.

Segue o início do meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int c = 0, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, min = 1, sub = 0;

    scanf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d", & c, & a, & b, & c);

    int vtl = a + b + c; //valor total das frutas

    if (c >= vtl) {

        printf("%d\n", min);

    } else if (vtl > c) {

        for ()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso basta decrescer a capacidade máxima da cesta no valor total de quantidade de frutas a cada iteração do laço, exemplo:

quantidade de frutas = 12
capacidade da cesta = 6

- Primeira iteração: 12 - 6 = 6
- Segunda iteração: 6 - 6 = 0

Como foram utilizadas duas iterações o tempo necessário foi 2 minutos.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void get_input(const char *texto, int *variavel);

int main(void)
{
  int fruta_a, fruta_b, fruta_c, capacidade_cesta;

  // Pega as entradas do usuário
  get_input("Digite a capacidade máxima da cesta: ", &capacidade_cesta);
  get_input("Digite a quantidade de fruta A: ", &fruta_a);
  get_input("Digite a quantidade de fruta B: ", &fruta_b);
  get_input("Digite a quantidade de fruta C: ", &fruta_c);

  // Variáveis para calcular o tempo total
  int tempo_total = 0;
  int total_de_frutas = fruta_a + fruta_b + fruta_c;

  // Calcula o tempo total
  // A cada iteração é decrescido do
  // total a capacidade da cesta
  for(; total_de_frutas > 0; total_de_frutas -= capacidade_cesta)
    tempo_total++;


  // Mostra a quantidade total de minutos
  printf("O tempo total foi de: %d minutos\n", tempo_total);

  return 0;
}

void get_input(const char *texto, int *variavel)
{
  printf(texto);
  scanf("%d", variavel);
}
```